# Magento Royal Mail Click and Collect type delivery option

Tags: shipping

Royal Mail offer a local collect service that I would like to put in as a shipping option so customers can choose a local collection point (a post office location) during checkout after searching for one (postcode lookup). I was hoping there would be an extension that connects the local collect service with Magento in terms of the post office locations available, or something of that nature. :)

Comment: Did you ever find one or did you build this yourself?

Comment: Never found one.  No plans to build one as we're moving away from Magento (sigh).

Answer (score 1):

We have developed this module for our Magento site. You can see it working at Lovemystyle.com. If you add a product to your basket and go to checkout and enter an address in the UK you will see a delivery option comes up called delivery to a local post office with a list of local post offices you can choose from.

The module allows you to offer different delivery speeds to the post office for different prices and it also creates the shipping label and books the delivery at the post office. The module cost us a lot to develop so we are offering it for sale also to get some of the cost back.

**It is available here:**

https://www.lovemystyle.com/parcelforce-convenient-collect-magento-module-click-collect-from-post-office.html